# UNIX shell scripting if and grep command setting

Tags: bash, unix, grep

To design a shell that accepts an input string which is a state name, and looks for all the universities that are in that state. If found, it displays all the universities as output, otherwise it displays an error message like “xxx was not found in the file”. Here xxx is the input string. (Hint: This can be done by redirecting the search results to a file and then checking whether the file is empty or not). For example, if the input string is “NSW”, the output should be a list of all the universities in NSW. If the input is “AUS”, an error message should be displayed, saying that “AUS was not found in the file”.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Please enter State of Uni (e.g NSW ; NAME MUST BE UPPER CASE)"
read State

if [ -n $State ]
then
    grep "$State" Aus-Uni.txt
else
    echo "$State was not found in the file"
fi

exit
```

There is no false statement popping up even the string that I entered was not found in the file. Somehow the true statement is roughly executed.

Comment: Double check what your if statement is checking.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Note that you could use: `if [ -z "$State" ]; then echo "You didn't type a state abbreviation" >&2; elif ! grep "$State" Aus-Uni.txt; then echo "$State was not found in the file Aus-Uni.txt" >&2; fi` ... which reports to standard error, and spots when AUS is not found, and other improvements.  You report the the state is not found only when the name given is empty — not quite what was requested.

Comment: Why are you taking the state as input instead of as an argument?  Just pass it as an argument and your entire script becomes `grep "$1" Aus-Uni.txt ||  echo "$1 was not found in Aus-Uni.txt" >&2`

Comment: When you passed the `-n $State` test and execute `grep`, the `else` code belonging to the `-n $State` test will not be reached. And please put quotes around `$State`.

Comment: Depending on the data format in Aus-Uni.txt, you should be able to use the `-i` option for a case-insensitive search, which would be a little more user-friendly than insisting that the user enters in upper-case.

Comment: This is extremely likely to produce false matches given you must have more text in your file than just the state abbreviations (are they ALWAYS 3 letters btw?). If you [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output we could help you do this the right way. @cdarke adding `-i` is bad advice, it'll make it far more likely to get false matches if the search is case insensitive (state `FOO` would then match state;universitiy `NSW;Food Polytechnic`).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you've no way to check whether the user input is compliant with your requirement that it should be all upper-case.

You could use [[ shell param expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to convert the input to all-uppercase before processing, well, something like :

```
echo "Please enter State of Uni (e.g NSW)"
read State
State="${State^^}" # Check ${parameter^^pattern} in the link
```

Change

```
if [ -n $State ]
```

to

```
if [ -n "$State" ] 
# You need to double-quote the arguments for n to work
# You can't use single quotes though because variable expansion won't happen inside single quotes
```

Comment: The OP cannot use `${State^^}` because the `#!` line says `sh`, not `bash` (even though the question is tagged bash).  `grep -i` instead?

Answer (score 2):

This only checks whether the string is nonempty

```
[[ -n $State ]]
```

The grep runs if the check succeeds - but the success of grep is not checked

Try this

```
if [[ -n $State ]]; then
  if ! grep "$State" Aus-Uni.txt; then
    echo "$State was not found in the file"
    exit 2
  fi
else
  echo "State is empty"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: hmm, also mention the reason for introducing `[[..]]` :)

Comment: Error messages should go to stderr, not stdout